# Set base class attribute values while loading object / creating objects yii

Tags: php, yii, base-class

I have two models which inherits from the common base class.

```
class Batsmen extends CPlayer{
    batsmen_id      // model field.
    batsmen_name    // model field.
}

class Bowler extends CPlayer{
    bowler_id       // model field.
    bowler_name     // model field.    
}
```

// Component class which serves as a base class for models batsmen and bowler models.

```
class CPlayer extends CActiveRecord{
    public player_id;
    public player_name;
}
```

I want to load the attribute values of Batsmen/Bowler to the base class CPlayer attributes while loading an object or after creating an object. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set batsmen_id to player_id after model loads use afterFind method:

```
protected function afterFind(){
  parent::afterFind();
  $this->player_id = $this->batsmen_id;
}
```

If you just initialize object use init

```
public function init(){
  parent::init();
  $this->player_id = $this->batsmen_id;
}
```

Comment: Ya i tried with afterFind. But its not invoking that event after i do findByPk.

Comment: findByPk by default always rise afterFind event. So it's possible somewhere error in your's classes logic

Comment: Yea. That was my mistake was using onAfterFind instead of afterFind. But for init() once i create a new object and save its not setting the value for parent attributes.

Comment: `create object != save model` :) Do assign in afterSave. Methods with on* using in another way.